# Push Message from ActiveMQ to Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, websocket, activemq-classic, stomp

I'm using Spring MVC, ActiveMQ and WebSocket(via `sock.js` and `stomp.js`) to build a real-time data delivery application.

As we know, when a producer(another desktop application) push a message to ActiveMQ, and the `onMessage()` method will catch it.

```
public class MessageReceiver implements MessageListener {
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.println(message);

        // How to push the message to a Controller in Spring?
    }
}
```

Most of the tutorials just print the message to the console.

I have another controller called `WebSocketController`:

```
@Controller
public class WebSocketController {
    @SubscribeMapping("/getRealTimeResult.action/{submissionId}")
    public Message getRealTimeResultAction(
            @DestinationVariable long submissionId) {
        return new Message("Message content from onMessage() method");
    }
}
```

I want to push the message received in `onMessage()` method to the `getRealTimeResultAction()` method. Can you tell me how to do it?

I know that the ActiveMQ can communicate with the browser using `stomp` via the port `61613`.

I don't want to do this because I think the MQ should be transparent to the user. Also I need to do some authorization in the `WebSocketController`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking an @Controller with @SubscribeMapping and @MessageMapping methods can handle subscriptions and messages from STOMP clients connected over WebSocket.

From your description it's not clear what you're trying to do. Was the message pushed to ActiveMQ via STOMP from a browser client or was it produced by some other back-end JMS client? Also the MessageReceiver receives an actual message while the @Controller method has an @SubscribeMapping method for handling a subscription from a STOMP client. It's not clear what you're trying to do. Please provide more information so I can provide a better answer.

Comment: First of all, the web client push a message (with a unique ID) to the ActiveMQ. Then a back-end JMS client(not in Spring MVC) received the message and push more messages to the ActiveMQ (asynchronized). So the `onMessage()` function in the Spring MVC will be invoked. And now I want to push the message to the Spring Controller. What should I do?

Comment: Are the @Controller and the MessageReceiver in the same JVM? If so you can use some notification mechanism (like Spring ApplicationContext events for example). Or depending on what you want to do, they could be sharing a data structure of some sort.

Comment: Yes, they are in the same web project. Spring ApplicationContext may not be a good choice. Any elegant implementation?

Comment: Spring 4.2 adds support for @EventListener https://spring.io/blog/2015/05/26/spring-framework-4-2-goes-rc1.